# Using capistrano 3.16.0 then cap: command not found

Tags: ruby, bash, macos, capistrano

I am able to install capistrano from my Gemfile `gem 'capistrano', '~> 3.16.0'`.
[image: capistrano installed]

However, bash can't find the cap command.
[image: cap command not found]

Not sure how to fix this one, I am running bash on my MacBook Air M1.

Comment: How about using `bundle exec cap .... `?

Comment: executing "bundle exec cap" instead of just "cap" seems to work. Do you know why is that? I was able to run just "cap" on my Intel-based Mac

Comment: you are using rvm or rbenv? Make sure your bash is loaded with correct ruby version & gemset in which the gem is installed.

Comment: I have installed ruby via homebrew and the correct version is loaded on my bash profile via export PATH="/opt/homebrew/opt/ruby@3.0/bin:$PATH"

Comment: also is it using correct gemset according to your project?

Answer (score 0):

**Why prepending `bundle exec` works?**

- Execute a command in the context of the bundle.
- This command executes the command, making all gems specified in the
  Gemfile available to require in Ruby programs.
- This ensures the executable script uses gem versions from that
  project's Gemfile, **not other versions installed system-wide** on
  the machine.

Essentially, if you would normally have run something like `rspec spec/my_spec.rb`, and you want to use the gems specified in the Gemfile and installed via bundle install, you should run `bundle exec rspec spec/my_spec.rb.`

[source](https://bundler.io/v2.4/man/bundle-exec.1.html)

**what if I don’t want to use `bundle exec`?**

*1. Use Bundler's binstubs*

For rbenv https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv/wiki/Understanding-binstubs#project-specific-binstubs

For RVM https://rvm.io/integration/bundler

*2. Set an alias for `bundle exec` in the computer’s .bash_profile or .zshrc for zsh.*

Ideally we would add alias `be='bundle exec'` to `.bash_profile` or `.zshrc` and run our executables with `be` prepended to the commands. Example: `be rake`.